# BackboneJS - How to create a "show more" button inside a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view, which shows a couple of articles/divs. I want to add a "show more" button. My original html looked like this:

```
<div id="ip">
    <article>
         ...some other html code
    </article>
    <button class="showmore">show more</button>
</div>
```

now, i load the article(s) through a view, which gets rendered in the div#ip. The button gets kind of "overwritten" or "kicked out" and is not accesible anymore. So how do i accomplish adding the button? Create another view? or initialize/render it in the view itself?

UPDATE:
Here is what I have in my router, its inside the initialize function:

```
this.recommendedArtistView = new RecommendedArtists({el:'#ip'});
self.recommendedArtistView.render();
```

and my view looks like this:

```
define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/Recommended.html'],

    function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {


        'use strict';

        var RecommendedArtists = Backbone.View.extend({

            template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

            events: {
            },

            initialize: function () {
            },

            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template());
                return this;
            },


        });

        return RecommendedArtists;

    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your Backbone View to the div#ip (el: "#ip" I assume?), then you can just use the events property:

```
events: {
   "click .showmore": "_onShowMore"   
}
```

And then define a _onShowMore function in your view to respond to it and do something.

If that's already what you are doing, then the problem is in your render function. There is no reason to replace the content of the whole View's element, in your render, you can do something like (assuming that your articles are in a backbone collection passed to the view):

```
render: function(){
   //Find the article node just below #ip (the current element for this view)
   var articlesContainer = this.$("article");
   //Empty it to re-render the collection of articles from scratch
   articleContainer.empty();
   this.collection.each(function(article){
     //toHTML could be a new Backbone View or just a article.get("content")
     articlesContainer.append(article.toHTML());
   });   
}
```

This way, the rest of the element (here, the showmore button) doesn't get erased. And so, the event will still be bound, no need to rebind it between DOM updates.

Comment: Thats great! Hmm, but one of my problems still is that the button is not getting rendered. I'm pretty new to this, so...

Comment: The whole point of this is that you don't need to render the button if it's already in the DOM. Bacbkone View are able to work on existing DOM or create their own elements. If you still have issues, then we need to see more code...

Comment: SHT, can we see the template? The this.$el.html(template()) has to be the culprit, because it replaces the whole content of #ip (which contains the button). So if the button is no longer here, the only reason I can fathom is that it's not in the template, somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by adding this to the render function in my view:

```
render: function() {
     $(this.el).html(this.template());
     $(this.el).append("<button class='btnwhite btnmore'>Show more</button>");
     return this;
},
```

Comment: can't the button be part of the template?

Comment: @Vic yes, i tried that like in the example above, but the <button> gets kind of kicked out and is not in the DOM anymore after rendering the view-template

Comment: Why would it get kicked out? It should work. Can you check what `this.template()` returns in the render function? Is the button there?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Enders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20378039/1746258), and i want to add that:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    $(this.el).find('.showmore').click = function () {
      // something you want
    }
    return this;
},
```

Comment: probably better to add the click event with backbone's event hash